# How to verificate a user AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)

Tags: appwrite

I have a problem verifying users, from what I saw in other questions it seems I need to have an active session but I don't know how to create the session if the user is not created yet

I'm trying to create a user and then verify, but doing `account.createVerification('localhost')` returns this error:`AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you log in after creating the account by calling `account.createEmailSession()`?